# How is it possible to disable L2 cache alone in Intel i7 processor?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, microbenchmark

I am trying to learn more about the replacement policy in Intel L1 caches. I am having an Intel i7-7700HQ processor. On going through the Intel Developers Manual Volume 3, I came across a CD bit which disables all the caches L1-L3. Is there anything that allows us to disable only the L2 Cache, so that L1 miss penalty becomes significant? If so, how?

Comment: You can find details on the replacement policies used by recent Intel CPUs at https://www.uops.info/cache.html

Comment: IIRC, there is some disable bit that only disallows the filling the cache but still allows loads and stores to use it. Other caching modes than WB (e.g. WP) could be useful but that's only for stores and you cannot measure their latency to mem. BTW **I don't think this is off-topic**, you may have, unfortunately, came across three unrelated users.

Comment: There is no publicly documented way to do that.